# Merge dataframes by checking if item is in list

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Pandas dataframes that I want to merge. The first dataframe has a column that contains a list of coordinate tuples. The second dataframe has a column that contains a single tuple of coordinates. I want to merge those dataframes based on whether the single coordinate tuple is contained in the list of coordinate tuples. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the two dataframes look like?

Answer (score 0):

*example data*

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a":[[(1,2), (3,4)], [(3,2), (4,4)], [(5,1), (4,3)]],
        "c":[10, 11, 12]
    }
)
```

df1:

```
                  a   c
0  [(1, 2), (3, 4)]  10
1  [(3, 2), (4, 4)]  11
2  [(5, 1), (4, 3)]  12
```

.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "b":[(1,2), (3,3), (4,3), (3,4)],
        "d":[20,21,22,23]
    }
)
```

df2:

```
        b   d
0  (1, 2)  20
1  (3, 3)  21
2  (4, 3)  22
3  (3, 4)  23
```

**solution**

create a dataframe which is similar to `df2` but has a column called `index` which indicates which list the tuple belongs to in `df1`

```
temp = (
    df1["a"]
    .explode()
    .reset_index()
    .merge(df2, left_on="a", right_on="b")
    .drop(columns="a")
)
```

`temp` looks like this

```
   index       b   d
0      0  (1, 2)  20
1      0  (3, 4)  23
2      2  (4, 3)  22
```

then we reset the index on `df1` and use the two "index" columns as a join key

```
df1.reset_index().merge(temp, on="index").drop(columns="index")
```

This gives us

```
                  a   c       b   d
0  [(1, 2), (3, 4)]  10  (1, 2)  20
1  [(1, 2), (3, 4)]  10  (3, 4)  23
2  [(5, 1), (4, 3)]  12  (4, 3)  22
```

It's possible you may want a different merge type, in which case adjust the parameters in the `merge` calls.